# Mocking browser requests on slow page

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

Condition: I have a page on a website that has a login form. This page available only from my local IP address and if user do nothing in 5 mins - it redirects to main page.

The issue: This page is in "black list" of my goverment, that's why they reduced speed of requests on this website to 1kbs. Page has scripts and styles with cachebusting. All of them synchronously uploading to the page. It takes more than 5 minutes.

How I can stub browser requests on page loading? What is more simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Load Page
2. Open Developer Tools in your browser (or right-click and select "Inspect")
3. Click the network tab
4. On the loading resources you would like to block, right-click it and select "Block URL"
   [image: Block a URL from browser]

This should permit you to reload the page without it reloading them as well for a certain duration of time.